# In ggplot2, how to display a legend using geom_hline function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my code:

`a<-c(1,2,3)
    b<-c(10, 20,30)
    data<-data.frame(a=a, b=b)
    p<-ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b))+geom_point()+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 7.69, linetype=2, size=1)`

As you see, the line is a dash line and also a chance level line, but there is no legend displayed in the plot, so how to add a legend with a title of "Chance line" and a dash line below it in the hline function or whatever other method?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add reproducible data and codes for ggplot? I am guessing you may want to use `annotate()` and add the text, "Chance line" next to the horizontal line?

Comment: Nope, I want a legend displayed in the top right corner of the plot. With a title and a dash line, which could not be done by `annotate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_hline` is special: its `show_guide` argument is `FALSE` by default, in contrast to most other geoms (presumably because `geom_hline` is so often used for annotation ...)

You didn't give a reproducible example before I initially answered the question, but this slightly hacked example seems to work:

```
library(ggplot2)
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
p + geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20),show_guide=TRUE)+
   scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=2)
```

The ugliness is because there needs to be something to show in the guide (legend); just saying `geom_hline(yintercept=20,lty=2,show_guide=TRUE)` doesn't work.  There's probably a more principled way to do this, though.

Comment: I would like to ask that how can I name geom_hline(). For instance, I want call as safetystock. Should use scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=2)?

Comment: Try `scale_linetype_manual(name="safetystock",values=2)` ?  I'm not sure.

Comment: you should ask another question, linking to this one and making it clear how your question is different.